# Centering a Layout within ScrollView. Kivy/KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a Layout in Kivy/KivyMD that is responsive, centered and scrollable. So far I have developed two layouts, one that centers a BoxLayout in a FloatLayout and that can be beautifully resized, however it doesn't scroll.
I have also developed a layout that is a GridLayout in a ScrollView, it resizes beautifully, but at large window sizes it doesn't center the GridLayout properly.

I have tried to put a BoxLayout within a FloatLayout in a ScrollView, it resizes beautifully BUT the scroll bar doesn't work.

I have so far been unable to combine the centered resizable Layout within a properly working scrollview. How should I accomplish this?

Here is my scrollview example:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


LIPSUM = """Very long lipsum..."""


Builder.load_string("""
<ExampleScroll@ScrollView>:
    do_scroll_x: False

    bar_width: 10
    bar_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
    bar_color_acrive: app.theme_cls.accent_color
    effect_cls: "DampedScrollEffect"
    scroll_type: ['bars']

    GridLayout:  # If FloatLayout and BoxLayout, doesn't scroll!
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        size_hint_x: .75
        size_hint_max_x: dp(800)
        size_hint_min_x: min(dp(400), root.width)

        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}  # Fails to center layout
        padding: 0, dp(16), 0, 0

        MDLabel:
            text: app.label_text + app.label_text
            halign: 'justify'
            padding: dp(16), dp(16)
            markup: True
            font_style: 'Body1'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

            text_size: self.size
        MDLabel:
            text: app.label_text + app.label_text
            halign: 'justify'
            padding: dp(16), dp(16)
            markup: True
            font_style: 'Body1'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

            text_size: self.size
        Widget
""")


class ExampleScroll(ScrollView):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    title = "Dialogs"
    label_text = LIPSUM

    def build(self):
        return ExampleScroll()


Example().run()
```

Here is my centering example:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


LIPSUM = """Very long lipsum..."""


Builder.load_string("""
<ExampleCenter@FloatLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        # Gives the BoxLayout a max and min width that is responsive
        size_hint_x: .75
        size_hint_max_x: dp(800)
        size_hint_min_x: min(dp(400), root.width)

        # Centers the BoxLayout horizontally responsively
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        padding: 0, dp(16), 0, 0

        MDLabel:
            text: app.label_text + app.label_text
            halign: 'justify'
            padding: dp(16), dp(16)
            markup: True
            font_style: 'Body1'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        MDLabel:
            text: app.label_text + app.label_text
            halign: 'justify'
            padding: dp(16), dp(16)
            markup: True
            font_style: 'Body1'
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
        Widget
""")


class ExampleCenter(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    title = "Dialogs"
    label_text = LIPSUM

    def build(self):
        return ExampleCenter()


Example().run()
```

How can I compile both of those and make it work?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is first, create a scrollview, if posible, you can use, RecycleView so you can easy add widget as Classes that have been defined as Widgets:

Example:

```py
class Thing1(AnchorLayout):
    pass

Kv ="""
<Thing1>:
    anchor_x: "center"
    MDIconButton:
        icon: "hi.png"


"""
```

Now, wherever your scrollview or recycleview widget id is defined, do the following:

```py
app.root.ids.scrollview_id_of_your_widget.add_widget(Thing1())
```

Or if you are using RecycleView

```py
app.root.ids.scrollview_id_of_your_widget.data.append({"viewclass": "Thing1", })
```

The widget on your scrollview will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `pos_hint` in a child of a `ScrollView` (which doesn't honor that property). So, rather than trying to center the child of the `ScrollView`, center the `ScrollView` itself. This means that the `ScrollView` must be placed inside a `Layout`. So, if you use `FloatLayout`, you can do something like:

```
<ExampleFL>:
    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        size_hint_x: None
        width: grid.width

        do_scroll_x: False
        bar_width: 10
        bar_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        bar_color_acrive: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        effect_cls: "DampedScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']

        GridLayout:  # If FloatLayout and BoxLayout, doesn't scroll!
            id: grid
        .
        .
        .
```

And create the `ExampleFL` class:

```
class ExampleFL(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

This sets the width of the `ScrollView` to the width of its child `GridLayout`, and uses `pos_hint` to center the `ScrollView` inside the `ExampleFL`. Then your `build` method would, of course, return `ExamplFL()`.

Comment: After applying your changes the **size_hint_x: .75**, **size_hint_max_x: dp(800)**, **size_hint_min_x: min(dp(400), root.width)** doesn't work anymore in the GridLayout and it misses out on beautiful resize of the layout.

Comment: You are again trying to use `hints` in the child of a `ScrollView`, which does not honor such properties. You can apply such hints to the `ScrollView` itself (becaue they are handled by the containing `FloatLayout`). You can also use `size_hint` for the children of the `GridLayout` (but not `pos_hint`), because again, they are handled by the containing `GridLayout`.

Comment: Can't achieve my desired results this way. I'll implement centering within ScrollView programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic implementation of centering view within ScrollView manipulating padding. This gives me the desired results.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


LIPSUM = """Very long lipsum..."""


Builder.load_string("""
<ExampleScroll@FloatLayout>:
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False
        bar_width: 10
        bar_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        bar_color_acrive: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        effect_cls: "DampedScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']

        ScrollCenterLayout:
            cols: 1
            rel_max: dp(800)
            rel_min: dp(400)
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            MDLabel:
                text: app.label_text + app.label_text
                halign: 'justify'
                padding: dp(16), dp(16)
                markup: True
                font_style: 'Body1'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            MDLabel:
                text: app.label_text + app.label_text
                halign: 'justify'
                padding: dp(16), dp(16)
                markup: True
                font_style: 'Body1'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
            Widget
""")


class ScrollCenterLayout(GridLayout):
    rel_max = NumericProperty(dp(800))
    rel_min = NumericProperty(dp(400))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollCenterLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.rel_max = kwargs.get('rel_max', dp(800))
        self.rel_min = kwargs.get('rel_min', dp(400))

    def on_width(self, instance, value):
        if self.rel_max < value:
            padding = max(value * .125, (value - self.rel_max) / 2)
        elif self.rel_min < value:
            padding = min(value * .125, (value - self.rel_min) / 2)
        elif self.rel_min < value:
            padding = (value - self.rel_min) / 2
        else:
            padding = 0

        self.padding[0] = self.padding[2] = padding


class ExampleScroll(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    label_text = LIPSUM

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightGreen"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return ExampleScroll()


Example().run()
```